# Parsing JSON for iOS app in Swift Issue

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

First of all, this is a noob question so anyone interested can answer me , because I'm just a beginner.
So, I need to parse JSON data from an api that my college seniors created for our annual technical festival. But they forgot to put a name to the array which contains all info.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVKuu.png)
They forgot to put the name and the role is similar to the "loans" at the beginning [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCcyi.png)
I am using SwiftyJSON to parse the data and here is my code.

```
func getJSON(){

    let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration:NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in


        if error == nil{

            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data:data!)
            let loan1 = swiftyJSON["loans"][0]["status"].stringValue
            print(loan1)
        }else{
            print("There is an error")
        }

    }
                task.resume()
}
```

So i would like to know that what could "loans" be replaced by to get my JSON parsing up and running. I have already tried " " and "" to be sure.
Thanks !

Comment: It's currently unclear to me what the complete JSON structure looks like. Could you post the entire JSON? Or at least the total structure of it?

Comment: That JSON doesn't really match your description and images.

Comment: I just want to know what can be substituted for "loans" in the above code so that I can parse the data as the array in the above api link doesn't contain an array name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the JSON dictionary you posted, you aren't accessing any existing keys so loan1 can't possibly be anything other than nil. Based on the response in the first image, you get back an array of dictionaries.

```
 [
    {
    "eid": 98,
    "ename": "Lights. Camera. Tweet",
    "sname": "IEEE GTBIT",
    "ebanner": "http://s10.postimg.org/a11cezdft/12045587_1594466984176579_4873790458939193947_o.jpg",
    "time": "1459189800854",
    "category": "Literary & Management",
    "desc": "Lights. Camera. Tweet! brings you a chance to win ..."
    },
    {
    "eid": 45,
    "ename": "Hack@GTBIT",
    "sname": "Android Techies",
    "ebanner": "http://i.imgur.com/ANR84uk.jpg",
    "time": "1459222200397",
    "category": "Technical",
    "desc": "Hack@GTBIT  is a Software Hackathon where particip..."
    },
```

etc...

If none of this data is what you're looking for, you're not requesting properly or the data being returned isn't being properly formatted or including all the necessary information.

It's possible you could make a new request to check the status using the ID or some other value; you would access that through swiftyJSON[0]["eid"] – that would get you the value 98. But the key–value pair you're trying to access isn't correct based on the response. The "loans" key doesn't exist at the top level and the "status" key also does not exist.